# How to reload sj:tab in struts2-jquery 3.3.3?

Tags: jquery-ui, struts2-jquery

I need to relaod a sj:tab in struts2-jquery 3.3.3, so far i tried:

- Add a listenTopic to sj:tab, didn't work as i read it wasn't yet
  implemented in that version
- Upon any event, reload the tab like:

> $('#myPanel').tabs("load", "#myTab");

It works and reloads, but some more event handlers bind and when i submit via sj:submit, it submits twice, i've tried to remove all event handlers with jquery before reload, but i doesn't make any difference. So the event handlers grow exponetially:

```
> $('#myPanel').tabs("load", "#myTab");  
1 event handler per button 
> $('#myPanel').tabs("load", "#myTab");
2 
> $('#myPanel').tabs("load", "#myTab"); 
4 .. 16 .. 32
```

How do i kill all those event handlers in sj:submit?

Comment: Hello, I think your question should be re-edited for the purpose of answering to it. Give some more details, thank you!

Comment: In a nutshell, how do people reload tabs in a sj:tabbedpanel?

Comment: Is your reloaded content injected with ajax each time?

Comment: Nope, i've multiple sj:submit, upon success i reload the tab with $('#myPanel').tabs("load", "#myTab");, but this loads in the current tab new events without discarding the older

Answer (score 0):

This was probably a bad smell from me as i needed to change a tab upon a new 'state' in the app, so i thought this would be a good idea:

```
( ajax call fired by a sj:submit --> POST )
# in the server check if the state changed, if so returns success and the client asks to reload.

$.subscribe("change_state"){
  ...
  $('#myPanel').tabs("load", "#myTab");
  # (http GET new tab)
};
```

The tab loads smoothly, but to prevent the old events to fire i had to setup variables for each button

```
$.subscribe("change_state", function(event){
  if (!reloaded){
     $('#myPanel').tabs("load", "#myTab");
     reloaded = 1;
  }
)};
$.document.ready(function(){
    reloaded = null;
});
```

If someone have the right design for this version of struts i'd gladly offer the 100 bounty